# Iterators are not acting the way I want. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: java

I'm working on a roulette-game as a beginner and I am stuck.

I have a chosen **Bin**-object

```
Bin(){
    outcomes = new TreeSet<Outcome>();
}
```

I have a **Bet**-object

```
public Bet(int amount, Outcome outcome){
    this.outcome = outcome;
    this.amountBet = amount;
}
```

that contains an **Outcome**-object.

```
public Outcome(String name, int odds){
        this.name = name;
        this.odds = odds;
    }
```

Goal - Iterate through all Outcomes in Bin and compare the Outcome.name's in Bin with bets.outcome.name's. If we have a mach, there is a win. If not, there is a loss.

So, this is my code:

```
System.out.println(bin.toString());
System.out.println(table.bets.toString());

System.out.println(black.toString());

ListIterator<Bet> i = table.bets.listIterator();
    Iterator<Outcome> b = bin.outcomes.iterator();

    while(i.hasNext()) {

        while(b.hasNext()){


            if(i.next().outcome.equals(b.next())){

                System.out.println("Win!");

            }
            else System.out.println("Win :/");
        }


    }
```

Problem: Even though the output reads:

```
[8 (35:1)]['7, 71' (17:1)]['8, 81' (17:1)][5, 53 (17:1)][8, 83 (17:1)][7 (11:1)][4, 41,    
43, 44 (8:1)][5, 51, 53, 54 (17:1)][7, 71, 73, 74 (8:1)][8, 81, 83, 84 (17:1)][4, 5,6,   
7, 8, 9 (5:1)][7, 8,9, 10, 11, 12 (5:1)][1 (2:1)][11 (2:1)][Low (1:1)][Even (1:1)]  

[Black (1:1)]

[10 on [Black (35:1)]]

Black (35:1)

No :/

Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
at java.util.LinkedList$ListItr.next(Unknown Source)
at Roulette.Game.main(Game.java:37)
```

It seems that it

**a)** Doesn't iterate through all outcomes in Bin
**b)** When it finds a match, it doesn't evaluate if as true.

Can you see what I am doing wrong?

Thank you so much for your help!!

I'm sorry if this is too much or too little text. Just in case you need to see what's going on in the other classes, here they are:

Game Class        https://gist.github.com/anonymous/5473187

Table Class       https://gist.github.com/anonymous/5473188

Bet Class         https://gist.github.com/anonymous/5473189

Outcome Class     https://gist.github.com/anonymous/5473191

Bin Class         https://gist.github.com/anonymous/5473192

BinBuilder Class  https://gist.github.com/anonymous/5473197

Wheel Class       https://gist.github.com/anonymous/5473200

NonRandom class   https://gist.github.com/anonymous/5473202

Passenger57 Class https://gist.github.com/anonymous/5473207

**Edit:** Removed System.out.println() and updated the new results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are calling each of `i.next()` and `b.next()` twice. `next()` goes to the next element, so if you have a sequence 1, 2, 3, 4 you print 1, 3 and compare 2, 4.

Copy the results to a variable to avoid this unintended side effect in the `println()` statements:

```
ListIterator<Bet> i = table.bets.listIterator();
Iterator<Outcome> b = bin.outcomes.iterator();

while(i.hasNext()) {
  Bet bet = i.next();
  System.out.println(bet.outcome.name.toString());
  while(b.hasNext()){
    Outcome o = b.next();
    System.out.println(o.name.toString());

    if(bet.outcome.equals(o)){
      System.out.println("Win!");
    } else {
      System.out.println("Win :/");
    }
}
```

P.S.:

The cleanest solution is probably to avoid iterators and to use for loops over the corresponding iterables.

Comment: @tore: You still did not copy the result of `next()` into variables. Hence you still call `i.next()` to often in the inner loop (which iterates over `b`)

Comment: Now you still call next() of the outer loop in the inner loop multiple times.

Comment: Ok, now there is a lot of action! :D

Thank you very much! I will study your answer in detail and try to understand what is going on! :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
while(b.hasNext()){
    String str = b.next().name.toString()
    System.out.println(str);

    if(i.next().outcome.equals(str))
        System.out.println("Win!");

    else 
        System.out.println("Win :/");
}
```

Instead of :

```
while(b.hasNext()){
    System.out.println(b.next().name.toString());

    if(i.next().outcome.equals(b.next())){    
        System.out.println("Win!");

    }
    else 
        System.out.println("Win :/");
}
```